What SQL Server user permissions are required for OpenTelemetry collector sqlserverreceiver?
I have managed to connect an OpenTelemetry otelcol-contrib collector sqlserverreceiver to an RDS SQL Server instance, but it only collects a single metric: sqlserver.lock.wait.rate
I have tried a number of different SQL Server permissions such as mapping to specific databases on the instance with db_owner and even connected it to the instance admin user, but still it does not collect any useful metrics.
There is nothing in the OpenTelemetry receiver documentation about what permissions the user requires. Am I missing something? Or is this not going to be compatible with an RDS instance of SQL Server?
Documentation I am referencing is here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/sqlserverreceiver
The collector config is:
  sqlserver:
    collection_interval: 10s
    username: otelcol
    password: ${env:OTELCOL_SQLSERVER_PASSWORD}
    server: ${env:OTELCOL_SQLSERVER_ENDPOINT}
    port: 1433
    resource_attributes:
      sqlserver.computer.name:
        enabled: true
      sqlserver.instance.name:
        enabled: true

The collector runs and does not show any errors in the console.
Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Try:
sqlserver:
    collection_interval: 10s
    username: otelcol
    password: ${env:OTELCOL_SQLSERVER_PASSWORD}
    server: ${env:OTELCOL_SQLSERVER_PASSWORD}
    port: 1433
    resource_attributes:
      sqlserver.instance.name:
        enabled: true
    metrics:
      sqlserver.database.count:
        enabled: true
      sqlserver.database.io:
        enabled: true
      sqlserver.database.latency:
        enabled: true
      sqlserver.database.operations:
        enabled: true

On your server, be sure the sql user you are using for the receiver has the following permissions:
Connect SQL
View any database
View any definition
View any performance
View server state
